# Updating the primefaces watermark messages dynamically

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to update the watermark messages dynamically based on the selected values from jsf selectOneMenu.The id being used for watermark component is "waterMark1".
The watermark component is linked to an input text field.
On valueChange , i get an error message that the id waterMarkID1 could not be located.
I tried updating an outputText based on the selectOneMenu selection and kept the id as WatermarkID1.It works fine with the outputText.

Is there any way to display the watermark messages based on the bean values.Any help would be appreciated.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{RequestBean.searchonType}" valueChangeListener="# {RequestBean.getValidateMsg}" id="searchUser">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{RequestBean.searchonTypeList}" />
                                <f:ajax event="change" update="waterMarkID1"  render="waterMarkID1"/>
                          </h:selectOneMenu>


                          <h:inputText id="searchTxt" styleClass="text_small" size="50" value="#{RequestBean.searchTxt}"/>

                          <p:watermark id="waterMarkID1" for="searchTxt" value="#{RequestBean.waterMarkID}"/>
```

Comment: Is the watermark component located in a form? If so, you probably have to prefix the id with `:<form name>:waterMarkID1` or something similar. It will probably also help if you looked at the actual generated id in Firebug (or similar) or just by "view source" in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can't update the `p:watermark` component directly. However, updating the container which holds that component will update your watermark message too:

```
<p:panel id="panel1">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{RequestBean.searchonType}" valueChangeListener="# {RequestBean.getValidateMsg}" id="searchUser">
        <f:selectItems value="#{RequestBean.searchonTypeList}" />
        <f:ajax event="change" render="panel1"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>


    <h:inputText id="searchTxt" styleClass="text_small" size="50" value="#{RequestBean.searchTxt}"/>
    <p:watermark id="waterMarkID1" for="searchTxt" value="#{RequestBean.waterMarkID}"/>
</panel>
```

Note that you can reduce the elements enclosed by the `p:panel`, for example, to `h:inputText` and `p:watermark` only. The key is to update the container, not the watermark component.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend updating the container that the watermark is enclosed in. In some cases you might have to update an entire form component and if you are updating the form component from inside the form you will be stuck in an infinite loop.
You can bypass this by enclosing the watermark in a  and then not render the panel.

```
<p:outputPanel id="watermark"  style="display:block">
     <p:watermark/>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Then simply update the outputPanel.